# html class replacement in JS is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change replace an html class based on value.For example if nsndatalength = 0 replace the class name with badge-success

```
function Awardstable(data) {

var container = document.getElementById('awardsTable');

data.forEach(function(awardsSnap) { // loop over all inventory
    var Items = awardsSnap.val();


    var nome = Items.Nomenclature;
    var NSN = Items.NSN;
    var AwardId = Items.Awardid;
    var AwrdDate = Items.Awarddate;
    var name = Items.Name;
    // var quant = Items.Qty;
    var cost = Items.Price;
    var key = awardsSnap.key;


    var NSNref = CatalogueDB.ref("NSNdata/" + NSN).orderByChild("NSN");

    if (NSNref) {

        // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
        NSNref.on("value", function(nsnshot) {


            if (nsnshot.val()) {
                var nsndatalength = Object.keys(nsnshot.val()).length;
            } else {

                nsndatalength = 0;

            }

            console.log(nsndatalength)
            console.log(nsnshot.val())


            var inventoryCard = `
                      <tr>
                                            <th scope="row">${NSN}</th>
                                            <td>${nome}</td>
                                            <td>${AwardId}</td>
                                            <td>${AwrdDate}</td>
                                            <td class="color-danger">${cost}</td>
                                            <td>

                                            <span class="badge badge-primary" id="sellerqty">${nsndatalength} Sellers</span>
                                            </td>
                                              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mb-1" id="buymodalbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyModal" onclick="buyModal('${NSN}')">
                      Buy
                  </button></td>
                                        </tr>


                    `;

            container.innerHTML += inventoryCard;


            if (nsndatalength == 0){

                var buybtn = document.getElementById('buymodalbtn')
                var qtymarker = document.getElementById('sellerqty')

                console.log("class",buybtn,qtymarker)


                document.getElementById("buymodalbtn").className = document.getElementById("buymodalbtn").className.replace
                  ( /(?:^|\s)btn-warning(?!\S)/g , 'btn-success' )

                  document.getElementById("sellerqty").className = document.getElementById("sellerqty").className.replace
                  ( /(?:^|\s)badge-primary(?!\S)/g , 'badge-success' )


            }

        })
    } else {
        nsndatalength = 0;
        console.log("No Awards Available")
    }

});

}
```

The problem is that the code is not working for all inventoryCard. This is the output of the html. The last item 0 sellers and buy button should also change color. What am I doing wrong from the code above?

[image]

Comment: instead of `className =` use `myElement.classList.add('badge-success')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn can you please add the modification as an answer. I'm not sure how to modify the code with your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) to toggle a class on/off, with the second parameter we can force it to be on/off.

Here we give the item a unique id:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary" id="sellerqty-${AwardId}">
```

then select it with:

```
document.getElementById(`sellerqty-${AwardId}`)
```

In your code it would look something like this by giving the item a unique id:

```
var inventoryCard = `
<tr>
  <th scope="row">${NSN}</th>
  <td>${nome}</td>
  <td>${AwardId}</td>
  <td>${AwrdDate}</td>
  <td class="color-danger">${cost}</td>
  <td>
    <span class="badge badge-primary" id="sellerqty-${AwardId}">${nsndatalength} Sellers</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning mb-1" id="buymodalbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyModal" onclick="buyModal('${NSN}')">Buy</button>
  </td>
</tr>`;

// Add it before we call getElementById
container.innerHTML += inventoryCard;

document.getElementById(`sellerqty-${AwardId}`).classList.toggle('badge-success', nsndatalength == 0)
```

Comment: that is because you are using `getElementById()` that is only going to select the first one. You will probably want to use a unique id.